# Code still executes after "quit" or "exit", Python, Spyder

Tags: python, exit, spyder

```
from os.path import join

string=" Congratulations, you are about to embark upon one of life’s "

path=r"C:\Users\Nord.Kind\Desktop"
file="test.txt"

quit() 

# This should not execute, but it does!!
with open(join(path,file),"w")as wfile:
    wfile.write(string)

wfile.close()
```

In the above code example the code still executes the write in file command, even though its after a quit.

The same behavious occures when I use exit.

I am using Spyder 3.6

Also the kernel restarts each time I use exit or quit.

Any help?

Comment: There's no way that code writes anything to a file, because it should throw a `NameError: name 'read' is not defined`. I don't know what code you're executing, but it's not the code you posted.

Comment: In spyder, there may be a residual `read` variable already defined from previous runs @Aran-Fey - The OP should restart the kernel and run the program with a clean kernel.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque The OP said the kernel restarts every time though. Something doesn't add up.

Comment: yes, I saw that after I commented... something does not add up.

Comment: I fixed the variable in my Post. Ofc it was named wrong.

The issue stands: using "quit()" and "exit()" wont stop the  code from writing into the file! Thats a behaviour I would not expect!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `sys.exit()` in lieu of `quit()`

```
import sys

...   # code that executes

sys.exit()

...   # this code won't execute
```

However, as noted by @AranFey in the comments, your code will throw an error if it attempts to execute the last part where the variable `read` is not defined.

Comment: Sys.exit does indeed work. However it stands the question why quit() and exit() both lead to a "reconnect to Kernel" and to the code writing stuff into the file.

Comment: Maybe a spyder glitch? Have you checked their mailing list, or their issues?

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Your question contains this comment:

> Also the kernel restarts each time I use exit or quit.

That's the behavior of the IPython kernel we use as a backend to execute users code. Those commands kill the kernel and that forces a kernel restart to maintain its associated console active. I'm afraid there's nothing you can do about it.

*Note*: The same happens in the Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SystemExit:

```
# Code that will run
raise SystemExit
# Code that will not run
```

[sys.exit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) also raises this error but this doesn't require importing `sys`.

Comment: "raise" does indeed work. However it stands the question why quit() and exit() both lead to a "reconnect to Kernel" and to the code writing stuff into the file.