# quit and exit do not work inside while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, exit

Using `Spyder` on `windows10`.

This keeps running infinitely when one might expect the code to `exit` if `i>3`:

```
import time

i = 0
while True:
    i+= 1
    print('hello')
    time.sleep(1)

    if i > 3:
        exit()
        quit()
```

So neither the `quit()` nor `exit()` functions work.

However, this does `exit` when `i>3`:

```
import sys
import time

i = 0
while True:
    i+= 1
    print('hello')
    time.sleep(1)

    if i > 3:
        exit()
        quit()
        sys.exit()
```

It is noted that the `break` function works, but the requirement is for the code to terminate (as opposed to breaking out of the loop and continuing).

It is also noted from this question ([Code still executes after "quit" or "exit", Python, Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797957/code-still-executes-after-quit-or-exit-python-spyder)) that this is a `spyder` issue.

Why is this the case and, given the above, what is the best way to exit a while loop preferably without requiring an `import` ?

Comment: `quit` and `exit` aren't normal parts of the Python language, they're just hints added in interactive mode so that new users can figure out how to leave the interpreter.  `sys.exit()` is what you should be using in an actual script.

Comment: "Why is this the case" I don't see how this is unclear from the linked duplicate; there's an answer from a Spyder maintainer that goes into detail. "what is the best way to exit a while loop" `exit` exits *an entire program execution*, not a while loop. If you want to exit an innermost `while` loop, use the `break` keyword - that's what it's for. To exit a function, use `return`. To exit an entire program, your options are to use such an import, raise an uncaught exception, or - almost always the right way - just reach the end of the program naturally, such that there is no more to do.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501121/difference-between-exit-and-sys-exit-in-python .

Comment: Addendum: to break multiple loops, normally it is best to refactor the code such that `return` gets you to the point in the algorithm where you want - i.e., make a function that handles just those loops. The *fact that you want that break* is a hint that the code is giving you, that the loops represent a process that deserves a name.

Comment: Depends on your installation; that script exits after 4 iterations on my machine, using `exit()` or `quit()`. Both are provided by the `site` module. You should use `sys.exit`, though.